# Solving for $T$ in this Algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I'm taking Physics E&M and I'm trying to solve the following equation for $T$.  I feel like the algebra I'm doing is correct but I cannot get the solution in the book which is $53.1 $C

> $K_{br}$ = brass = $109.0 \frac{W}{mK}$
>
> $K_{cu}$ = copper = $385.0 \frac{W}{mK}$
>
> $A=.000500m^2$
>
> $L_{br}=.200m$
>
> $L_{cu}=.800m$
>
> $T_H=100$C
>
> $T_C=0$C

$K_{br}A\frac{T_H-T}{L_{br}} = K_{cu}A\frac{T-T_c}{L_{cu}}$

$L_{cu}K_{br}A\frac{T_H-T}{L_{br}}=K_{cu}AT-T_c$

$L_{cu}K_{br}AT_{H}-T=L_{br}K_{cu}AT-T_c$

$L_{cu}K_{br}AT_H=L_{br}K_{cu}AT-T_c+T$

$L_{cu}K_{br}AT_H+T_c=L_{br}K_{cu}AT+T$

$L_{cu}K_{br}AT_H+T_c=T(L_{br}K{cu}A+1)$

$\frac{L_{cu}K_{br}AT_H+T_c}{L_{br}K_{cu}A+1} = T$

The correct answer is **53.1**C but I get 31.480

Clearly there is a problem with my Algebra somewhere.  Can anyone see it?

Comment: After the blue part: how does the second line come to being from the first one?! You did **not** have $\;T_c\;$ in the first line, for example...and also $\;T_H\;$ on the right side disappeared.

Comment: I modified it, I'm sorry I had a typo. @Timbuc

Comment: Still something must be wrong, as if the first equation in the white part is correct, then we can cancel $\;A(T_H-T)\;$ in both sides, and we'd then get: $$\frac{K_{br}}{L_{br}}=\frac{K_{cu}}{L_{cu}}$$ And **still** $\;T_c\;$ appear magically in the second line!

Comment: ...and are you sure that $\;T_C= 0\;$ ??

Comment: @Timbuc I'm positive that $T_C=0$ and what do you mean it magically appears on the second line?  It's on the first line too.

Comment: Hehe Yes @Inqui, after you changed the question who knows how many times, it **finally** is in the first line, too...and if $\;T_c=0\;$,  then why in the world to include it in the question? You could have saved yourself, and us, that.

Comment: @Timbuc you're right, but I just wanted to include everything just incase I messed up somewhere hehe

Comment: Ok, but then observe you can take it off the first equation, and you can *also* cancel $\;A\;$ in both sides of it as it is multiplying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first equation in the white part (after the blue one) is correct:

$$\begin{align}&K_{br}A\frac{T_H-T}{L_{br}}=K_{cu}A\frac{T-T_c}{L_{cu}}\\{}\\
&K_{br}L_{cu}(T_H-T)=K_{cu}L_{br}(T-\overbrace{T_c}^{=0})\\{}\\
&(K_{cu}L_{br}+K_{br}L_{cu})T=K_{br}L_{cu}T_H\\{}\\
&T=\frac{K_{br}L_{cu}T_H}{K_{cu}L_{br}+K_{br}L_{cu}}\end{align}$$

Now input the corresponding values and check we get what you say we should.